# Matrix formation, there is something wrong in the loops

Tags: php

I am trying to get this kind of matrix:

```
1 0 0 0 5
0 2 0 4 0
0 0 3 0 0 
0 2 0 4 0
1 0 0 0 5
```

and here is the code:

```
$n = 5;
$flag = 0;

for($i=1; $i<=$n; $i++){
    for($j=1; $j<=$n; $j++){
        if($i == $j){
            echo "$i ";
        }else{
            echo "0 ";
        }

        if($j == $n - $flag){
            echo $n - $flag." ";
            $flag++;
        }

    }
    echo "</br>";
}
```

the output is:

```
1 0 0 0 0 5 
0 2 0 0 4 0 
0 0 3 3 0 0 
0 0 2 0 4 0 
0 1 0 0 0 5
```

there is something wrong in the middle. I think it is because two for loops overlap there.
How to fix thiis?

Comment: can you put `$i<$n` in the first condition and try again?

Comment: @KraneBird, it wont work) to be honest, it got worse :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code to output the array you want:

```
$n = 6;

for($i=1; $i<$n; $i++){
    for($j=1; $j<$n; $j++){
        if($i == $j){
            echo "$i ";
        } else if ($j == $n - $i) {
            echo $n - $i ." ";
        } else {
            echo "0 ";
        }
    }
    echo "</br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason isn't an overlap in the loops. Its an overlap of the two `if` statements.

In the inner loop, you *always* print 6 things.

```
for($j=1; $j<=$n; $j++){
    if($i == $j){        // <--- This will always print in each iteraton (i.e 5 times)
        echo "$i ";
    }else{
        echo "0 ";
    }

    if($j == $n - $flag){   // <--- This will print once in the loop (the 6th extra)
        echo $n - $flag." ";
        $flag++;
    }

}
```

Since `$j` is equal to `$flag`, you don't need to keep track of it.
Change it to this ([Check it on ideone](http://ideone.com/AfqUGO)):

```
for($j=1; $j<=$n; $j++){
    if($i == $j){
        echo "$i ";
    } elseif($j == $n - $i + 1){
        echo $n - ($i-1)." ";
    } else {
        echo "0 ";
    }
}
```

Comment: @JohnyStark Yeah, I forgot about the flag. It should work now and theres a link to a working example.